# Why Don't .Flash and .Redirect Fire for Route in a Node.js Express Project?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, flash-message

I'm using [flash](https://github.com/expressjs/flash) widely in my Node.js Express application, but for one route I can't get flash or redirect to work. Views are with [pug](https://pugjs.org/api/getting-started.html):

```
form.permissive(action=`/setPermissive/${device._id}/${device.allowUnlock}` method="POST")
  label.groupTitle(for="setPermissive") Allow Unlock
    button.switch(type="submit" name="setPermissive")
      label.switch
        if (device.allowUnlock)
          input(type="checkbox" name="setPermissive" checked)
        else
          input(type="checkbox" name="setPermissive" )
        span.slider
```

route:

```
router.post('/setPermissive/:id/:permissive', catchErrors(deviceController.changePermissive));
```

controller:

```
exports.changePermissive = async (req, res) => {
  const permissive = (req.params.permissive === "false") ? false : true;
  const device = await Device.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: req.params.id },  { $set: { allowUnlock : !permissive } }, {
    new: true
  }).exec();
  req.flash('success', `Successfully updated ${device.name}`);
  res.redirect('/devices');
};
```

I know `Device.findOneAndUpdate` executes because I can see it in the backend, but I do not get the flash message, I do not get redirected, and the UI does not reflect the update. If I manually refresh the page, I get the flash message and the UI is updated.

I have similar routes that flash and redirect as expected, e.g.:

```
form.form(action=`/changeStatusEnabled/${device._id}/${newStateEnabled}` method="POST")
  input.button(type="submit" value=`${currentStateEnabled}` onclick=`return confirm('${msgConfEnabled}');`)

router.post('/changeStatusEnabled/:id/:state', catchErrors(deviceController.changeStatusEnabled));

exports.changeStatusEnabled = async (req, res) => {
  const myBoo = (req.params.state === "enable") ? true : false;
  const device = await Device.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: req.params.id }, { $set: { isEnabled: myBoo }}, {
    new: true
  }).exec();
  req.flash('success', `Successfully updated ${device.name}`);
  res.redirect(`/devicesAdmin`);
};
```

What am I missing?

Comment: So I figured out if I take off the class "permissive" it works as expected. I.e. I changed `form.permissive(action=...` to `form(action=...` and it flashes and redirects as desired. I have no idea why however :-|

Comment: You can post your solution as an Answer so it helps others. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason the `.permissive` class causes the hiccup. If anyone might know why, I'm all ears.

changed:

```
form.permissive(action=`/setPermissive/${device._id}/${device.allowUnlock}` method="POST")
  label.groupTitle(for="setPermissive") Allow Unlock
    button.switch(type="submit" name="setPermissive")
      label.switch
        if (device.allowUnlock)
          input(type="checkbox" name="setPermissive" checked)
        else
          input(type="checkbox" name="setPermissive" )
        span.slider
```

to:

```
form(action=`/setPermissive/${device._id}/${device.allowUnlock}` method="POST")
  label.groupTitle(for="setPermissive") Allow Unlock
    button.switch(type="submit" name="setPermissive")
      label.switch
        if (device.allowUnlock)
          input(type="checkbox" name="setPermissive" checked)
        else
          input(type="checkbox" name="setPermissive" )
        span.slider
```